# How can I change the team formation in pro clubs?

Tags: fifa-14

I have recently created my online pro and created a new pro club for him to join. The default team formation is 4-2-2-2.

Is there anyway to change this? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Formation of your Pro Club in the Match Lobby, simply select 'ANY' as your field Position, and you become the Manager/Captain of that game and can then change the Formation by pressing and holding L1. Another option appears on the bottom left of your screen labelled 'Arrange Friendly'.